# Convert variable that contain string data into JSON Object for JavaScript REST API

Tags: javascript, json, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Here I have variable named item and contain following data:

```js
{
  __metadata: {
    "type": "SP.Data.ClinicalTestingPhaseIIListItem"
  },
  Control: 1,
  Randomization: 2,
  Blindings: 3,
  Groups: 4,
  DoseTitration: 5,
  Stratification: 6,
  PatientsDoseLevel: 7,
  TumourResponse: 8,
  DetermineWarrants: 9,
  Title: 1
}
```

Now when I pass it to my ajax call written below that gives me a error after some research I get conclusion that the data passed in string format instead of object.

> **`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException`:** A node of type `PrimitiveValue` was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A `StartObject` node was expected.

Below is my ajax call

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: header,
        success:function(){
        alert("List itme Inserted Sucessfully");    
        },
        error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
                alert(data.responseText);
        alert("Error Occured");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove JSON.stringify and see

```
jQuery.ajax({

        url: requestUri,
        type: "POST",
        data: item,
        headers: header,
        success:function(){
        alert("List itme Inserted Sucessfully");    
        },
        error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
                alert(data.responseText);
        alert("Error Occured");
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi Mathews thanks for your reply but after removing JSON.stringify i got following error."Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content."}" please help u aware about this error.

Comment: @ManojAhuja that error may be because there must be some mismatch in the JSON that you are sending and the service expecting. The error looks like your JSON have some additional stuff which is not handled by the service.